ROS2 Navigation2 Configuration for Dynamic Environment
I am currently deploying an AMR for logistics use case in a Warehouse based on ROS2 Humble. It is a traditional warehouse where the environment is changing frequently (every 15 minutes). Almost all of the static feature of the environment could be blocked by the dynamic-static object (the object could stay for 10-15 minutes). The robot is expected to run every 10 minutes with a 5 minutes trip delivering object from point to points.
Whenever I tried to make a map and do navigation it works but only for several trip. After several time and environment changes, the AMCL packages kind of confused to localized the robot and tends to put the robot nowhere.
Is it a good practice to use the lifelong mapping feature from slam_toolbox for this cases? Should I do regular map serialization to updated to the latest map?
